# Why is my if statement code producing wrong output?

Tags: javascript

I want this if statement code to display the result that correspond to the declared variable, but I end up getting the wrong answer(Saturday) which I think is wrong, why?

```
let day = "Monday";
if (day = "Saturday")
{
    console.log("Today is Saturday");
}
else if (day = "Sunday")
{
    console.log("Today is Sunday");
}
else 
{
    console.log("Day does not exist");
}
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment. For comparison use `==` or `===`.

Comment: You're using `=` which is assignment. You want `===` for strict equality. A useful coding strategy to avoid this is to put the value on the left side always, since if you accidentally type `"Sunday" = day`, it will error since you can't assign to a string.

Comment: When you use the = sign once it is an assignment to a variable.
To check if two values ​​are equal to each other, you must insert two == signs

For example:
let x = 2
Now X=2
if{
x==2
}

Answer (score 2):

You are using the single = which is the assignment operator. Use the `===` to compare two strings.

```
let day = "Monday";
if (day === "Saturday")
{
    console.log("Today is Saturday");
}
```